# html + CSS: Make position relative some other element?

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I'm building a tree using lists in lists the ordinary way.
Now, what I would like to do is to have an extra label
that is absolute (horizontally) to the start of the outermost tree.

The effect I'm trying to achieve is the below, where the farLeft are labels
on each li (see similar html below):

[image: Tree]

I can easily do this, but my css will be unclean, to say the least, something
along the lines of:

```
/* each indentaion level is 20 px to teh right, so I need to offset */
ol.topLevel li label.farLeft { position absolute; left=-218px; ...}
ol.topLevel li ol li label.farLeft { position absolute; left=-238px; ...}
ol.topLevel li ol li ol li label.farLeft { position absolute; left=-258px; ...}
```

A usage could be like the below, but with more nesting levels:

```
<ol class="topLevel">
  <li>
     <label>Some niceLabel</label>
     <label class="farLeft">Far left text</label>
  </li>
  <ol>
     <li>
        <label>Some niceLabel</label>
        <label class="farLeft">Far left text</label>
      </li>
  </ol>  
</ol>
```

The above sucks in many ways, notably I have to change value in plenty of places if I move something, and I have to make one line per indention level.

Is there a better way to solve this, perhaps make my 'left' being the left of my top level tree, or some other good html mechanism.

It might be the time to mention I'm a total css newbie, so I  might easily have
missed somethnig completely obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here its fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/5YKFa/6/

### css

```
ol.topLevel{
    padding-left: 100px;
}
li{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.left {
    position: absolute; left:0px;
}
```

### html

```
<ol class="topLevel">
  <label>Top Level</label>
  <li>
     <label class="left">Label</label>
     <label>1</label>
  <ol>
     <li>
       <label class="left">Label</label>
       <label>1.1</label>
     </li>
     <li>
       <label class="left">Label</label>
       <label>1.2</label>
     </li>
  </ol>  
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: See my previous comment to Jeff: I donät understand how that solves
what I tried to create. Feel free to bug me again if I'm unclear,
this obviously is harder to explain that i thought :)

Comment: Can you create a visual version of what you want? I think i didn't get what u exatcly need

Comment: Sure, see edited version of my question, hope it clarifies somewhat.

Comment: Edited my answer too, hope it help

Answer (score 1):

Is the 'farLeft class being used elsewhere on the page? If not, the easy solution would be:

```
.farLeft { position: absolute; left:0px; ...}
```

Absolute positioning should line up automatically with it's parent container at 0px. So if you wrap a relatively positioned div around it you should be able to adjust margins and whatnot to get the result you are looking for.

You don't need to specify where everything is in the dom structure, unless you only want it to apply there, and even then using an id on the tag would be a better solution.  Good luck

Comment: hmm.. now that I think of it, are you attempting to line them all up with the left edge of the page? .farLeft{position:absolute; left:0px} should accomplish that

Comment: Perhaps I'm very unclear alternatively I don't understand your 
suggestion. From the example above, I would like my 'farLeft'
labels be vertically aligned with the left of the 'topLevel' class.

The other labels should be a nested tree as usual.

I can't see how your suggestion solves that, but as I said, I might
have totally misunderstood something, it's not uncommon :)

Did I make it clearer or am I far out and should sleep?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just use a margin on each level of the nesting, so it will grow the deeper you go.